# Как заставить exim писать результат доставки в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, exim

У меня есть такая схема:

Основной сервер и несколько мейл-серверов. На каждом мейл-сервере установлен **exim** и есть реализованная отправка через **phpmailer**. Логи доставки парсятся на php и затем заносятся в mysql.

Недавно из-за увеличения объема писем начала заканчиваться память на мейл-серверах.

Как можно заставить **exim** сразу писать лог доставки в mysql или хотя бы запускать скрипт php в который передавать параметры?

Answer (score 1):

До exim письма как добираются, через вызов срипта sendmail? Это дефолтовое поведение почты php, насколько я знаю.

Можно настроить php.ini на вызов вашего скрипта, который будет писать в базу, затем обращаться к эксимовскому sendmail.

Настройка почтового скрипта php: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mail.php
Поиск текущего sendmail: `which sendmail`